# Adding index to large mysql tables

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

I have a table

> | base_schedule_line_items | CREATE TABLE `base_schedule_line_items` (
>     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `installment` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>     `on_date` date NOT NULL,
>     `actual_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
>     `payment_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `scheduled_principal_outstanding` decimal(65,0) NOT NULL,
>     `scheduled_principal_due` decimal(65,0) NOT NULL,
>     `scheduled_interest_outstanding` decimal(65,0) NOT NULL,
>     `scheduled_interest_due` decimal(65,0) NOT NULL,
>     `currency` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2013-01-06 14:29:16',
>     `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2013-01-06 14:29:16',
>     `loan_base_schedule_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>     `lending_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>     `reschedule` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
>     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>     KEY `index_base_schedule_line_items_loan_base_schedule`   (`loan_base_schedule_id`),
>     KEY `index_bslt_spd` (`scheduled_principal_due`),
>     KEY `index_bslt_lending` (`lending_id`),
>     KEY `index_bslt_actualdate` (`actual_date`),
>     KEY `index_bslt_spsila`   (`loan_base_schedule_id`,`scheduled_principal_due`,`scheduled_interest_due`,`actual_date`),
>     KEY `index_bslt_ondate` (`on_date`),
>     KEY `index_bslt_oa` (`on_date`,`actual_date`),
>     KEY `index_bslt_ol` (`on_date`,`loan_base_schedule_id`),
>     KEY `index_bslt_oli` (`on_date`,`lending_id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30410126 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

Now this table has 30 million records in it, I need to add two more indexes to this 
and its like it takes years to add it.

> alter table base_schedule_line_items add index index_bslt_sla     (scheduled_principal_due,actual_date,lending_id);
>   alter table base_schedule_line_items add index    index_bslt_ssla(scheduled_principal_due,scheduled_interest_due,lending_id,actual_date);

I used the below mentioned query to find out size of table

> SELECT table_name AS "Tables",  round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 /  1024), 2) "Size in MB"  FROM information_schema.TABLES  WHERE table_schema =   "my_database_name";

The result came out as

base_schedule_line_items       |   20111.00

I used this just to calculate data length and left out index length

> SELECT table_name AS "Tables",  round(((data_length) / 1024 /  1024), 2) "Size in MB"  FROM information_schema.TABLES  WHERE table_schema =   "my_database_name";

and result was

> base_schedule_line_items       |    9497.00

The indexes

> KEY index_bslt_actualdate (actual_date),
>   KEY index_bslt_spsila   (loan_base_schedule_id,scheduled_principal_due,scheduled_interest_due,actual_date),
>   KEY index_bslt_ondate (on_date),
>   KEY index_bslt_oa (on_date,actual_date),
>   KEY index_bslt_ol (on_date,loan_base_schedule_id),
>   KEY index_bslt_oli (on_date,lending_id)

were added by me, but I am not fsure or what purpose other indices were added for. This is fairly big application . Now i need to add those two indices mentioned above as they help me extracting a report using a select statement and I find it very difficult to add them. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (Recent versions run _some_ ALTERs much faster.)

Comment: did you tried  replace adding indexes from `alter table ...` with `create index BLALA on....` ? its much faster !

Answer (score 21):

The activity of altering big tables are done in phases:

1. Create a new table with required fields and indexes say in test DB (just structure)
2. Dump the data from the existing table and load the same to the newly created table in test DB
3. Now announce your downtime :)
4. Swap the tables by renaming - `RENAME table ur_db.table_name to test.temp, test.table_name to ur_db.table_name, test.temp to test.table_name;` This is an atomic operation taking fraction of a second.
5. Load the extra records to the newly created table ( the records that came after dumping and then loading). This step can be done before Step: 3 also once to reduce your downtime.
6. And your system is back

Few notes:

1. You need not hit information schema directly like this, try using `SHOW TABLE STATUS from db like 'table_name'`
2. The speed of alter table is more or less linked with the I/O speed. Last time when we ran a direct alter table(without the above steps), we had 40GB+ table size it took around 4hours. If your 20GB data is taking years, you are working on some outdated machine.
3. Also drop of the unwanted indexes like `index_bslt_ondate, index_base_schedule_line_items_loan_base_schedule` as some other indexes has the left most column as the indexed column

Please let me know if you need any clarification on any of these steps.

Edit : A simple python script to automate the process https://github.com/georgecj11/hotswap_mysql_table.git

Answer (score 12):

You can use a tool like [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html) to add the index without blocking your application. The basic logic is as follows:

- create empty copy of the table with the new index
- add triggers to the existing table so that any changes that hit the table will be applied to the copy of the table*
- start copying the rows from the old table to the new
- once the copying is completed, swap the tables out
- drop the old table

* The tool doesn't work if there are existing triggers on the table

The swapping and dropping behavior can be adjusted based on options passed to the tool.

Also, there are issues with foreign keys, so be sure to read the documentation of the tool to fully understand what it's doing.

And of course, it is wise to make sure you have a backup of the table to be able to restore if needed.

Answer (score 0):

When adding `INDEX(a,b)`, you should drop `INDEX(a)` as being redundant.

In newer versions of MySQL, ADD/DROP INDEX is very fast.  (Check the details; there are caveats.)

You can combine the `ALTERs`; this may speed things up.

`DECIMAL(65,0)` takes 29 bytes and probably has far more significance than you will ever use.  Consider using an 8-byte `DOUBLE` or some other datatype.  Since such values are included in the data and in multiple indexes, the savings is repeated.  Changing a datatype forces the rebuilding of the table.